# How do I make a gwt-ext window not resize when its content resizes?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-ext

I've run `setHeight(600)` on a [Window](http://gwt-ext.com/docs/2.0.4/com/gwtext/client/widgets/Window.html), that's it's initial size. I've also went ahead and done `setAutoScroll(true)`.

When the content of the window resizes, the window itself resizes. What I want is for the window to stay fixed in size, and when the content grows larger, add scrollbars.
I can get this if I resize the window manually, then let the content grow or shrink.

Comment: Have you tried the AutoHeightis setter since then? Maybe it could make A.Rex's answer acceptable.

Comment: peterh: This was just over seven years ago. I don't use GWT any more. I'm not sure I could even validate this without having to relearn and setup a mock project.
I think this questions should be closed rather than having an answer accepted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the validity of the only answer is already undecidable by the OP. (See OPs comment above.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the feature provided by GWT - [`setAutoHeights(false)`](http://gwt-ext.com/docs/2.0.4/com/gwtext/client/widgets/BoxComponent.html#setAutoHeight%28boolean%29)?